# PHP PDO Many to Many Condition creats multiple field

Tags: php, pdo, many-to-many

I am trying to make a many to many condition table in php, where multiple people have multiple invoices, but the results are not arranging the way i want.

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txVLL.jpg

I would like to make a list of invoices for each person in only one cell, like: 6   Rafael  rafel@test.com  [1, 2] <- these 2 should stick in one cell without the extra generated Column (I have no idea why that happens at this time)

I am not sure how to approach this. Thanks for your help in advance!

tables

```
people
id name email
1 test test@email.com
2 test test@email.com
....

inv
id inv_no value status
1 001 100 ok
2 002 300 no
....

people_inv
people_id inv_id
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

class sql-s:

```
public function viewdatamodel($table)
{
    $row = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC");
    $row->execute();
    $query = $row->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $query;
}

public function viewdatajoin($table)
{
    
    $row = $this->db->query("
    SELECT people_inv.people_id, GROUP_CONCAT(people_inv.inv_id) AS invoice_id, inv.status 
    FROM people_inv 
    JOIN inv 
    ON people_inv.inv_id = inv.id
    GROUP BY people_inv.people_id");
    
    $row->execute();
    $query = $row->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $query;
}
```

table

```
$table = 'people';
$results = $data->viewdatamodel($table);
$invoices = $data->viewdatajoin($table);

<table border="1">
    
    <?php
     
    $no = 1;
     
    foreach($results as $result){
        
    ?>
    <tr>
    
        <?php 
        
        echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
        
        
        
        echo '<td style="display: none;">'.$result['id'].'</td>'; 
        echo '<td>'.$result['name'].'</td>'; 
        echo '<td>'.$result['email'].'</td>'; 
        
        foreach($invoices as $invoice){
            
            if ($result['id'] == $invoice['people_id']) {

                echo '<td>'.$invoice['invoice_id'].'</td>';

            }else{

                echo '<td>-</td>';

            }
        
        }
        
        ?>
        
        <td>
        
            <a href="<?php echo 'edit.php?id='.$result['id'].'&table='.$table; ?>">EDIT</a>|
            <a href="<?php echo 'lib/process.php?action=delete&id='.$result['id'].'&table='.$table; ?>">DELETE</a>
            
        </td>
        
    </tr> <?php $no++; } ?>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like for the simple case you can use group_concat(inv_id) and call it a day

Comment: I updated my code with GROUP_CONCAT(people_inv.inv_id) AS invoice_id and GROUP BY people_inv.people_id, but now I get extra cells which I have no idea what's generating them: https://imgur.com/a/jh72G2g

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Seems it was just the wrong order of the Table elements that were inside my php. Now they display superbly!